# Why do we use a singular noun which is related to more than one person?

Tags: grammar, nouns, verb-agreement

Why isn’t “mobile phone” plural in the following sentence?

> 70 percent of the population of the world own a mobile phone.

Comment: No particular reason. I wouldn't like to say which is more common, but there's absolutely nothing unusual about the plural version *70 percent of the population of the world own **mobile phones**.*

Comment: It has a distributive meaning, where "a mobile phone" (singular) is owned by each member of the set of 70 percent of the population.

Comment: Because they each own their own (singular) mobile phone. Though the plural is also OK.

Comment: "70 percent of the population of the world own a mobile phone" uses the _distributive singular_ and implies (in the less rigorous sense) a 1-to-1 relation more strongly than "70 percent of the population of the world own mobile phones" does. However, neither demand a 1-to-1 or an each-person-to-many-phones ('many' here = 2+) relation.